# How to dynamically alter the class of an Html.ActionLink in MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, html-helper, actionlink

I'm looking for a way to alter the class of an ActionLink in the controller based on specific criteria (not found in the model so I can't write a conditional in the view itself).  But i can't seem to find the ViewData("name") that allows me to work w/ this element (I assume this is possible, but I'm missing something).

I have an html helper like so in my view

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Home")%>
```

But in my controller I'm not sure how to reference this, like the below to add an attribute like class or onclick.

```
ViewData("View").attributes.add("class", "active")
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't set CSS attributes from the controller since that's a concern of the view. You can add HTML attributes to the ActionLink like this:

```
 <%=Html.ActionLink("View Cases", "Index", "Home", new { @class="active" })%>
```

Alternately you can build your anchors "manually":

```
 <a href="<%=Url.Action("Index", "Home")%>" class="active">View Cases</a>
```

Or if you need to conditionally set the active class:

```
 <% var activeClass = someCondition ? "active" : ""; %>
 <a href="<%=Url.Action("Index", "Home")%>" class="<%=activeClass%>">View Cases</a>
```

Comment: agreed, but in the case where I need to show / hide a menu option based on user credentials (webforms convert to MVC) - how can I do such in MVC?

Comment: For showing/hiding based on credentials, either surround with an if block or write an HtmlHelper extension method to encapsulate the logic. You can pass a value from the controller if the user is authenticated then check for that in the view.

Comment: thanks for helping me make the paradigm shift!  I enjoy the clean separation this provides!

Answer (score 2):

In a [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) view you can do something like this:

```
@model AssessmentQuestionViewModel

@{var newClass = Model.AnswerValue == 0 ? "not-answered" : string.Empty;}

<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="wizard-step @newClass">View Question</a>
```